# candle chart with different time frame GMMA

Tags: time, frame

Hi could someone tell me how to use different time frame GMMA in one chart?
For example, one same chart shows 5 minute candle with 1 hour GMMA. Now my chart can only show 5 minute candle with 5 minute GMMA, 30 minute candle with 30 minute GMMA, 1 hour candle with 1 hour GMMA etc. Thank you!

I do not know anything about writing codes.